# Outlook plugin move mail item is slow

Tags: c#, move, outlook-addin, mailitem

I'm working on a plugin for outlook that moves emails to a folder.
Is working fine but looks like the move method of MailItem is slow take 4-5 seconds to move 10 emails
I'm using something like

```
for (int i = folder.Items.Count; i > 0; i--)
{
     Outlook.MailItem mi = (Outlook.MailItem)theRootFolder.Items[i];
     if (mi != null)
     {            
              mi.Move(destFolder);         
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use multipls dots in the single line of code:

```
 folder.Items.Count
```

Break the chain of property and method calls and declare each call on a separate line of code. Thus, you will be able to release underlying COM objects instantly. Use [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx) to release an Outlook object when you have finished using it. This is particularly important if your add-in attempts to enumerate more than 256 Outlook items in a collection that is stored on a Microsoft Exchange Server. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object. Read more about that in the [Systematically Releasing Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623945%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article in MSDN.

Be aware, the `Move` method of the MailItem class returns an object which should be released after.

Comment: Hi Eugene, thanks for replay, unfortunately there are no improvements, looks like after move one email Outlook is trying to read the next one and is spending time on this